How to modify navigation bar to have dropdown menu?
How can I improve my current HTML navigation bar so that it displays a drop down menu without JS?
I am trying to edit the investment menu in the navigation so that it displays a drop down:
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown"><input type="checkbox" id="dropdownToggle1">
    <label for="dropdownToggle1">Investments</label>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/templatemo_591_villa_agency/stock%20investment.html">Stock investment</a>
      <a href="#">Real Estate</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Apply</a></li>
  <li><a href="property-details.html">Property Details</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Schedule a visit</a></li>
</ul>

Full code on CodePen
I inserted a <li class="> tag for the list within the unordered list and a <div class="dropdown-content for the actual drop down and included them both in my CSS, all of which can be found in my CSS on  y work in Codepen.

Please provide your current relevant CSS in the question

@ZachJensz  this is my CSS: https://hastebin.skyra.pw/dojelafajo.css

Please include your CSS in the question by editing your question

Your currently given codepen example never shows anything but the preloader. (Could be due to the fact that you are referring to local images using the file protocol, I suppose - none of us here has those on their local machine.)

You already inserted a checkbox input into your markup there, which I am guessing is part of the attempt to solve this - so where did you get that "inspiration" from? Looks to me like you found some tutorial - but applied only half of it? The way this works, is that you use a combination of the :checked pseudo class, and the adjacent sibling or general sibling combinator, to target a following sibling based on the checkbox state ...

@CBroe yes I did get it from a random tutorial  and yes I applied some of it but not all because I think I only needed to apply what was necessary for my template
